# Branch.io deep links on iOS - Params not shared when app opened with universal links

Tags: ios, deep-linking, branch.io, ios-universal-links

I'm using the branch.io API to create deeplinks send by email to our users. When creating the link I add some metadata for the iOS app like the `deelinkpath` and other useful data.

I'm able to see these params when I copy the branch link and open the iOS app manually. And it works also when the link opens safari first before redirecting to the app.

However if the link opens the app directly from the email (universal link), branch doesn't recognise the link and returns

```
["+clicked_branch_link": 0, "+is_first_session": 0]
```

Any idea on what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please mention the ESP you are using? Further can you check if AASA is being generated or not? https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/ios-troubleshooting#section-validate-if-aasa-file-successfully-downloaded

Comment: Hi Kartik! We use Mandrill but not the Branch integration. We generate the link with the Branch API and then send the email using the Mandrill API from our backend.  On the AASA, this is the line I have in the console `Already downloading data for domain sa….ap….link, so skipping a second download`

Comment: @KartikShandilya To add more information, if I do a long press “Open in [App Name]” the link works and the params are retrieved.

Comment: Could you please let me know if Mandarill is enabled as an ESP in your Branch Dashboard > Emails?

Comment: @KartikShandilya not it's not. But I have disabled wrapping on the Mandrill side and even when I copy the link from the email, paste in the Notes app and click on it the data sharing doesn't work (the app opened via universal links but link is not recognised as branch link)

Comment: @KartikShandilya do I need to enable Mandrill on the dashboard to make this work?

Comment: Wondering if it's an issue with the Scene Delegate as our app is built for iOS 13 and above?

Comment: @KartikShandilya do you any idea please?

Comment: can you share the details at support@branch.io so that we can support you and recheck on your confguration?

Comment: ok thanks a a lot. Will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was related to a wrong implementation of the Scene Delegate methods to manage the continue user activity as we support only iOS > 13.0.

This new version of the Branch iOS SDK doc explains how to fix the implementation for apps using Scenes: https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/ios-basic-integration#section-apps-using-scenes